# Form submit renders ajax partial showing code in text with Paperclip attachment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, paperclip, erb

The files upload fine, and the form submission goes through with a Paperclip attachment, but the partial it's supposed to render through ajax shows up as text on a new page, instead of rendering the modal partial.   Otherwise, without a Paperclip attachment, the form goes through normally as well, but the partial also renders normally. This is what shows up on the page, the code as text:

```
$("#actionEdit").html("Thank you, application received :)  \n\n<br><br>\n\nYou will receive an Update regarding your application within one business day.\n");
```

And it shows up at http://localhost:3000/support_tickets.js which is wrong, should be just localhost. The pictures upload though, and the form submits normally. If there is no attachment, the page renders normally.

the form:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <%= f.input :house_insurance_image, hint: "Upload a picture of your house insurance if you plan on holding an event at your house."  %>
</div>
```

controller:

```
def create
    @support_ticket = current_fan.support_tickets.build(support_ticket_params)
    authorize @support_ticket, :create?

    @fan = Fan.find(@support_ticket.fan_id)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
end
```

create.js

```
...
<% elsif @support_ticket.save %>
    $("#actionEdit").html("<%= j render 'success' %>");
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue was I was uploading in a modal, which requires gem remotipart.